# Cryptographic Primitive Method

Tags: encryption, hash, random-number-generator, mac, hmac

Is there any cryptographic primitive bijective (one-to-one and onto) function for creating cryptographic tools like symmetric encryption/decryption, Hash code generator, MAC, HMAC and Random number generator?

Comment: I don't really get your question. You can build most symmetric primitives from a blockcipher with a block size of at least 256 bit that's not vulnerable to related key attacks. For example you could build all of the above from threefish.

Comment: is it possible to build the above mentioned tools using a symmetric stream-cipher?

Comment: A stream cipher is a rather inflexible building block. It might be possible, but it won't be pretty or efficient. Don't do that. If you want a universal building block, use a block cipher(that's what I recommend), or an unkeyed permutation like what keccak uses. There are simple ways to create stream ciphers, hashes, MACs etc. from a wide block cipher.

Comment: Is there any stream-cipher (or cryptographic hash function)  based on one-to-one and onto function/process?

Comment: I still don't get your question, but keccak's building block is a unkeyed permutation. Permutations are bijective. Keccak can be used as a hash, MAC, stream cipher and RNG.

Comment: Sorry for troubling you.

What I want is, 

a stream cipher with two modes Mode-1 (encrypt/decrypt) and Mode-2 (decrypt/encrypt) 

i.e. it should be possible to encrypt and decrypt using Mode-1 and Mode-2 respectively and also it should be 
possible to encrypt and decrypt using Mode-2 and Mode-1 respectively.

Is it possible? if so let me know such stream cipher?

Comment: @Auth: Did you post that last comment on the wrong question?

Answer (score 3):

As CodesInChaos notes, a secure [block cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher) satisfies all the criteria in your question:

- An $n$-bit block cipher is a (keyed family of) bijective function(s) on the set of $n$-bit bitstrings.
- A block cipher can be used for symmetric encryption in any of several [modes of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation).  In some of these modes (notably OFB and CTR) the block cipher effectively acts as a keystream generator for a synchronous [stream cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher).
- A block cipher can be used in several ways [to construct a one-way compression function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_compression_function#Construction_from_block_ciphers), which in turn can be used to construct a [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).  Indeed, most commonly used cryptographic hash functions are based on block ciphers.
- A hash function constructed from a block cipher can certainly be used in the [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) construction, but there are also several ways (such as [CBC-MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBC-MAC), [OMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-key_MAC) and [PMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PMAC_%28cryptography%29)) to construct a MAC directly from a block cipher.
- As noted above, a block cipher in CTR or OFB mode becomes a stream cipher, which is essentially the same thing as a [cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator).

Indeed, insofar as there exists a "universal building block" in modern cryptography, block ciphers are it.  Pretty much the only thing they *cannot* do is [public-key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography).

That said, block ciphers certainly aren't the *only* possible building block.  For example, a cryptographic hash or pseudorandom function can be used in the [Feistel / Luby–Rackoff construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher) to construct a block cipher, which can then be used to construct all the other things described above.

Comment: It's important to note that constructing a hash from a block-cipher isn't possible for any block-cipher. The standard assumption of the cipher being a PRP (pseudo-random-permutation) isn't enough for a secure hash. It needs large blocks (256 bits for a 128 bit sec level) and must resist related key attacks (at least for Davies-Meyer). These mean that it's difficult to construct a hash from AES.